# Externalise validation rules JSF

Tags: java, spring, validation, xhtml, jsf-2

we want to do business rule validation outside our java code using some xml etc.we are using Spring 3.1 and JSF 2.0.i tried to search but cudn't found concrete on placing business rule outside our java code.i will thankful if someone can provide direaction for this

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you are looking for but you can use Hibernate annotations in place of hard coded validators in JSF 2.

These are just a few examples of this.

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/urubatan/archive/2006/09/aspectj_hiberna.html

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1GA/reference/en/html/validation.html

Comment: thanks for links..basically we are looking for doing validation outside Java Code